# Video Views are replacing their position in a grid view and sometimes 1 video view is repeating in a grid view

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, baseadapter, android-videoview

Basically I have a list of videos I want to show all of the videos in a grid view and keep them playing repeatedly for example if 1 video reach to its end then it should start again.I have manged it all in my adapter code given.. Now here comes the problem the issue I am facing is on scrolling the grid view the items of a grid view (a single item of grid view consists of a video view and a delete button ) sometimes swap with one another or sometimes a single video view gets repeated in grid view.. It also have another abnormal behavior that the last item of grid sometimes stick to bottom of screen .. I just don't get it whats happening here..

```
public class MyGalleryAdapterMain extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity mActivity;
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        private ArrayList<File> mDatalist;

        public MyGalleryAdapterMain(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<File> mDatalist) {
            this.mActivity = mActivity;
            this.mDatalist = mDatalist;

            mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mDatalist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v=convertView;
            final File mData=mDatalist.get(position);
            final Holder mHolder;

            if(convertView==null){


                v=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,null);
                mHolder =new Holder();

                mHolder.mDeleteButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

                mHolder.mVideoView=(VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
                mHolder.mVideoNameTextView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoNameTextView);

                v.setTag(mHolder);

            }else

                mHolder=(Holder)v.getTag();

       /* Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mData.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
       mHolder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);*/

            if(mHolder.mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()==0) {
                mHolder.mVideoView.setVideoPath(mData.getAbsolutePath());
                final Holder mTempHolder=mHolder;

                mHolder.mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mTempHolder.mVideoView.start();


                    }
                });

                mHolder.mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mTempHolder.mVideoView.start();

                    }
                });
            }







            mHolder.mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mData.delete();
                    mDatalist.remove(mData);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }



        public class Holder{

            private VideoView mVideoView;
            private TextView mVideoNameTextView;
            private Button mDeleteButton;

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think its because the recycled videoviews you are using arent being told to reset themselves when being reused so they just play the same video they were previously playing. You should do a stop or release (Im not looking at android docs right now) and then re-load the video view on reuse. I dont see you doing that in your code you posted.

Comment: Thanks A lot for the answer...
But If i reload the videoViews on reuse dont you tink it will load the videos from start again ? to handle this issue i put the  if(mHolder.mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()==0)  statment in getview() so that all videoViews must be loaded  single time and then keep playing .... And why should i stop or release them beacuse i want them to keep playing in a continuous mode like a gif image  plays in a loop..

Comment: I think its because videoViews sit ontop of the mediaplayer api and Im pretty sure that telling the views mediaplayer to release the content is the only way to make sure that in the recycled videoview isnt using the mediaplayer from a previously loaded Uri. Just to make sure I would try to explicitly tell the videoView to release so that the underlying mediaplayer stopped playing the wrong content. Im just guessing but thats my hunch.